# Need to schedule a cloud function with only allow internal traffic only

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have a Google Cloud function that needs to run routinely every day at 7:30 PM IST with the Ingress connection set to **Allow Internal Traffic only**. How do I accomplish this?

Comment: Use cloud scheduler ;)

Comment: Thanks for your comment @guillaumeblaquiere. I already tried the Cloud Scheduler. Since the cloud function accepts the internal connection only, the scheduler can't invoke the function. Kindly help me to get out of this.

Comment: Please specify what error you get, I'm trying the same and see that it's a permission error. So question could be rephrased: What permission does the SA in Cloud scheduler require to invoke a function where Ingress is set to ALLOW_INTERNAL_ONLY?
Did you solve it by the way?

Answer (score 0):

It does not appear to be possible (2023-02-21), see the [issue tracker with Google](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/183498983?pli=1).